# Futility analysis sample size

Tags: sample-size, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have been asked to determine the sample size needed to demonstrate futility in a small study. I suggested going the "traditional route" and conducting an interim analysis at a pre-specified timepoint or sample size to determine whether or not to continue (likely via conditional power), but I'm wondering if there is a reasonable method for just providing the sample size a priori. The only thing I can think of is to determine sample size based on beta (Type II error), but I don't see how that would be different from determining sample size based on power.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I am familiar with most of these terms in the context of group sequential clinical trials. If that's the case, then calculating the information bounds for a sequential analysis is quite difficult. On top of usual considerations (baseline hazard function, relative risk for treatment), it also depends how many interim analyses you intend to conduct and how you decide to "spend your alpha". Even with those wrinkles worked out, the process of calculating power is quite difficult. I'm aware of one tool that is capable of doing this, [RCTDesign](http://www.rctdesign.org/Welcome.html)